# adding custom claims to identity server 4 GrantValidationResult

Tags: c#, access-token, identityserver4

As per http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/reference/grant_validation_result.html I'm trying to add extra claims to a GrantValidationResult but the extra claims arent showing up just wondering where i could be going wrong here:

```
var extraClaims = new List<Claim> {
new Claim("resource_id", resourceId) 
};
context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(
subject: bobIdentity,
authenticationMethod: "custom", 
claims: extraClaims); 
return;
```

Comment: I have the same problem...